# Packing Points into Region

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, packing-problem

In a $64\times 200$ region, the distance between any two points must be at least $25$.

> What is the maximum number of points that can be placed inside the region? The most I could fit was 30.
>
> What if they were placed in the most *space-inefficient* way? (Least number of points present such that no more can be placed)

This has to do with random obstacle generation in a game I'm working on.

Comment: This is equivalent to packing circles of diameter $25$ in a $(64+25)\times(200+25)$ rectangle.

Comment: Packing problems are often hard because the optimal arrangement is hard to find and hard to prove. You could visit packomania to get ideas of what the configurations look like.

Comment: At least $30$ using a hexgonal packing. here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iQQC.png) for the configuration.

Comment: I got 32; see my comment on [C Monsour's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2745489/856). I will be pleasantly surprised if this can be improved.

Comment: @Rahul judging from the [best known packing of 34 circles in a rectangle](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/crc_var/crc34_0.399786245706.html) on packomania. if one want to pack circle of diameter 25 on a rectangle with width 225, the height need to be around 89.95. This suggest 34 is impossible for this problem and your number 32 really looks like the optimal one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the rectangular region is $w = 64$ by $h = 200$, and $R = 25$ is the minimum distance between any pair of points, and points are allowed to reside on the perimeter of the region, then the number of points you can put within the rectangular region cannot exceed $N$,
$$N \le \left \lfloor \frac{4 (w + R)(h + R)}{\pi R^2} \right \rfloor$$
because each point excludes a circular region whose area is $\pi\left(\frac{R}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{\pi R^2}{4}$.

In this case, $N \le \lfloor 40.794595 \rfloor$ i.e. $N \le 40$.

From circle packing, we know that not all "area" is used in this way; that you cannot cover all of a surface with non-overlapping circles. In practice, it means that the true, absolute number is somewhat less. (Even the shape, or aspect ratio of the rectangle, matters.)

I am not aware of any methods of finding the actual absolute number of circles/disks/points, because there is an infinite number of positions for each point within the area. Since this is for a game, I'd expect the above known absolute upper limit to suffice, and the actual number of obstacles to vary.

Comment: I wonder if there is a result saying that in any packing each circle excludes at least the area of the circumscribed regular hexagon, since you can't pack circles any closer than that. If that's the case, it would give a tighter upper bound of 36 points.

Comment: @Rahul: True. For myself, that would definitely be enough to use that in a computer program, i.e. $$N \le \lfloor \frac{4(w+R)(h+R)}{\sqrt{12}R^2} \rfloor$$ (with a comment on the derivation including that the area of an infinite plane covered by identical discs is at most $\pi/\sqrt{12}$). However, I don't know how to prove that; I haven't read the L. Fejes Tóth paper from 1940 (proving the hexagonal lattice to be the densest) to see if it proves this too. (In other words, I do believe a bit of research along those lines would indeed yield a better upper bound. I just showed the trivial one.)

Comment: L. Fejes Tóth published a paper (in English!) in 1950 which covers the case of packing into a convex polygon of 6 or fewer sides. Rahul's comment is an application of Theorem 1 from that paper, since it applies to rectangles. I haven't had time to read and understand the proofs, there, unfortunately.

Comment: Fejes Tóth's paper is available as open access from the journal website: [*Acta Sci. Math.* 12A](http://pub.acta.hu/acta/showCustomerVolume.action?id=4771&dataObjectType=volume&noDataSet=true&style=)

Answer (score 1):

I can fit 26 of them if some of them are allowed to be on the edge, using hexagonal packing which is optimal for large regions (three columns lengthwise, two of 9 points each that touch the ends, interleaves with one columns of 8 points each).  If you make this one unit wider, I could fit another column, and get 34.  I suspect that if you take a 64x200 rectangle and slide it around a hexagonal pattern with the points 25 apart you will find an oblique angle where more than 26 dots are covered.  But if you can change the region to 65x200, life will be much easier.

Comment: @C Monsour How did you get 4 columns?

Comment: Because I misread it as 65x200.

Comment: You can get 4 columns if you allow the hexagonal packing to get squashed a bit. Then you can't fit 9 points in a row, but you still get 8 in each, for a total of 32 points: https://i.stack.imgur.com/akEMI.png

Answer (score 1):

Since any two points cannot be closer than 25 units, picture each point as the center of a circle with a radius of 25 units, which is the same as a circle with a diameter of 50 units. 4 such circles could be placed one on top of each other in a 64-unit wide by 200-unit high area.

It might look something like this (You have to assume they're touching):

O
O
O
O

Along the top of the uppermost circle, you could have 3 points (upper left corner of the region, 25 units to the right of that point, and then another 25 units to the right).

Similarly, you could have another set of 3 points going through the center of the uppermost circle, and along the bottom of the uppermost circle. Each of these would be exactly 25 from its nearest neighbor. So, the first circle has given us 9 such points.

Each of the other circles is going to add another 6 such points (not 9, because the last set of 3 from the previous circle is the same as the first set of 3 from the new circle). So, that's 3 more circles with 6 points each, or 18 more points.

Adding this result to the previous 9, we get 27 points. I am unfortunately unable to prove this is a maximum, but it does seem like a good starting point.