# Packing Points into Region with Variable Distances

Tags: recreational-mathematics, packing-problem

This could be linked to the [Packing Points into Region](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2745472/packing-points-into-region) question. I have a rectangular grid with some positions occupied and need to place different types of points into the region with the distance constraint only applied on points of the same type.

As an example, one could consider types A, B, and C, with a minimum distance of 4, 2, and 1, respectively. This would mean that points of type A cannot be closer than 4 from each other, type B cannot be closer than 2, and so on.

There is no such restriction on points of different types which means that A and B can be placed next to each other in the grid.

My question is: Can one calculate whether it is possible to place a certain number of such points into a rectangular grid?

So far, I have read about different ways to solve the circle packing problem, and I am wondering if one could calculate the possibility before trying to place the points given a certain number of points against each type.

I am providing an example grid with some points that need to be placed.

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5VWn.png)

Type = A, Required Amount = 12, Minimum Distance = 2

Type = B, Required Amount = 44, Minimum Distance = 1

Type = C, Required Amount = 9, Minimum Distance = 4

Type = D, Required Amount = 12, Minimum Distance = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming with a binary decision variable $x_{ijt}$ that indicates whether unoccupied cell $(i,j)$ is assigned type $t$.  Let $a_t$ denote the required amount for type $t$.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\sum_t x_{ijt} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \tag1\label1\\
\sum_{i,j} x_{ijt} &= a_t &&\text{for all $t$} \tag2\label2\\
x_{i_1j_1t} + x_{i_2j_2t} &\le 1 &&\text{for $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$ that are too close for type $t$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{1} enforces at most one type per cell.
Constraint \eqref{2} enforces the required amount for each type.
Constraint \eqref{3} enforces the minimum distance requirement.

For your example data, one feasible solution is as follows:

```
X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 
X A C A   B D B D B C D   B C X X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X C B   B     D B B B X X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X A D B     B   B   D D X X X X X X X X X 
X X X X X X B   B D D B B D B B B B A B B A B B A X 
X X X X X X B B B B B B B B B C B B B B B B B B B X 
X X X X X X C B A D A C X X X X X A B A C A D A C X 
X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Is x going to be the vector that we try to maximize here? I am a bit confused as to how one would calculate an objective value from this.

Comment: The question is whether there is a feasible solution, so you can omit the objective or, equivalently, use a constant zero objective function. Alternatively, you can maximize $\sum_{i,j,t} x_{ijt}$ while relaxing \eqref{2} to $\le a_t$. If the resulting optimal solution satisfies these constraints with equality, then you have found a feasible solution to the original problem.

Comment: Awesome! I'm assuming this could be used with something like a branch and cut algorithm to decide if a certain subtree can be ignored.

Comment: Yes, I called a MILP solver that uses branch and cut.